# java JComboBox doesn't update (via model)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've created a small application that reads data about university subjects from an XML file.
I can add new subjects, etc.
My problem however is that I have another frame with a JComboBox in it which is filled only via one method, which is called whenever I make a change (either reading from an XML file or adding a subject which is then added to my JTable and the XML file).

When I initially start my application it will automatically open a default XML file and read the contents, and add every subject to the combo box, just as I want. However, subsequent calls (like adding a subject or opening a new file) seem to have no effect, whatsoever.

The code in question:

```
    public void fillComboBoxSubject(ArrayList<Subject> subjectList)
    {
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> cbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();

        for ( Subject subject : subjectList )
        {
            cbm.addElement( subject.getName() ); //getName() returns a String
            System.out.println(subject.getName());
        }

       comboBoxSubject.setModel(cbm);
   }
```

The println will display me every single subject if I open a new file, the combo box is not updated, though.

Regards,
LML

edit: SSCCE
Contains all appearances of the combo box:

```
public class FEnterMark extends JFrame
{
    private JComboBox<String> comboBoxSubject;

    public FEnterMark()
    {
        comboBoxSubject = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBoxSubject.setBounds(83, 8, 140, 20);
        contentPane.add(comboBoxSubject);
    }

    public void fillComboBoxSubject(ArrayList<Subject> subjectList)
    {
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> cbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();

        for ( Subject subject : subjectList )
        {
            cbm.addElement( subject.getName() );
            System.out.println(subject.getName());
        }
        comboBoxSubject.setModel(cbm);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I've tried that before, but it appears to have no effect. Does it make a difference if the JFrame the combo box is in is currently disposed?

Comment: @peeskillet You don't need to revalidate(). Swing will automatially revalidate() and repaint() a component when a property is changed.

Comment: revalidate doesn't change anything.

Comment: *"Does it make a difference if the JFrame the combo box is in is currently disposed?"* - It's possible. You may have an incorrect reference to the combobox that is actually visible

Comment: You probably have defined comboBoxSubject twice. If it doesn't work then you don't have a reference to the combobox that is displayed on the frame. Maybe you have two references to the combobox, once as an instance variable and once as a local variable. Post a proper `SSCCE` that simulates your problem.

Comment: The thing is that it works once: when I start the program. It will fill my combobox with the same contents as are in the XML file and printed via System.out.println(). Every subsequent call only prints to the console anymore.

Comment: That is NOT a SSCCE! Not only does it not contain valid data or compile, you don't show your "refresh" logic which it the part the causes the problem. What is the point of showing the code that works??? We have given you the probable cause, so it is up to you to do some debugging.

Comment: The problem was indeed that the window was disposed.
The refresh logic calls that method of an active (and only) object. The code that didn't do what it should've was the one at hand, though? as the new model wasn't being taken into the combobox.

Comment: The disposed window should not matter. You can still update the model of the combo box. Then when you later invoke setVisible(true) all the components should be painted in their updated state.

Comment: After disposing the window and then making the method call to fill the combo box from another window it wouldn't update the combo box, which lead me to coming here (as I didn't think about that beforehand). I changed to call the method from a windowlistener which uses a new inner class extending WindowAdapter and implementing the windowActivated method.